# Grounding a device with double insulation prohibited?

Tags: insulation

There are Class I and Class II electrical devices. Class I devices need to have live parts grounded and Class II have double insulation. Why grounding of class II devices is prohibited? I mean, we can make double insulation and additional have connection to the ground.

Comment: there no harm in grounding the exposed parts of a class II device.

Comment: I think it would mean it prevents the device from being *rated* as double insulated, as there is now a ground conductor piercing the insulation, where the point of double insulation is to be able to neglect the ground conductor.  There is really no reason you couldn't double or quadruple insulate a grounded device, but double insulated tools are probably used intentionally in cases where having a ground conductor would be unsafe for the user, so they may consider it to be defeating the safety and voiding the rating or something.  Can you provide links to the material you are quoting?